# How would I go about getting my code to detect multiple periods (AKA . )

Tags: c++

Im building an arithmetic calculator, I have error checking for everything, but multiple .'s as an example 12.34 is allowed, but 12.3.4 shouldn't be because of the multiple .'s how would I implement that into my code? I dont know how to stop my "if" statement that looks for .'s because it skips over multiple one when all I want it to do is let any numerical number that is a legal decimal through such as 12.34

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>   


using namespace std;

const double MAXRANGE = pow(2.0, 16.0); // 65536
const double MINRANGE = -pow(2.0, 16.0);

bool validDouble(const char* argument)
{
    return atof(argument);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    

    char z;

    bool isARealDouble = true;
    
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        z = 0;
    }
    else if (argc == 4)
    {
        z = argv[3][0];
    }
    else if (argc < 3)
    {
        cout << "P" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (argc > 4)
    {
        cout << "P" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if ((z == 'a') || (z == 's') || (z == 'm') || (z == 'd') || (z == 'p') || (z == 0))
    {


        if (z == 0)
        {
            float h;
            float x = atof(argv[1]);
            float y = atof(argv[2]);
            if (x <= MINRANGE)
            {
                cout << "R" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (x >= MAXRANGE)
            {
                cout << "R" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            if (y <= MINRANGE)
            {
                cout << "R" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (y >= MAXRANGE)
            {
                cout << "R" << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
            {
                isARealDouble = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)
                {
                
                    cout << argv[i][j] << " ";
                    if (isdigit(argv[i][j]) || argv[i][j] == '.')
                    {   
                        isARealDouble = true;
                                            }
                    else
                    {
                    isARealDouble = false;  
                    cout << "X" << endl;
                    return 0;
                    }
                        
                }
                
                
            }
            if (isARealDouble)
            {
                h = x + y;
                cout << h << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }

        
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convert the C string to a `std::string` and use `std::count`

Comment: How would i do that, Im brand new to c++ coding

Comment: What is the point of the line `if (isARealDouble)`? That `if` condition will always be true when it is evaluated, because your program won't ever reach that line if `isARealDouble` is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the C string to a `std::string` and use `std::count`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    auto args = std::vector<std::string>{argv, argv + argc};
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < args.size(); ++i) {
        const auto count = std::count(args[i].begin(), args[i].end(), '.');
        if (count > 1) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: simpler: `auto args = std::vector<std::string>{argv, argv + argc}`

Comment: @underscore_d Wouldn't this create a vector with 2 elements?

Comment: wouldn't that mean i would need # include <vector> ? I cant do that with the parameters I've been given, i can only use the libraries i am given

Comment: @ThomasSablik It doesn't for me with `g++ -std=c++17`. Why would it?

Comment: @underscore_d It does for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MoqtuuTB3Jl2jLwa

Comment: @ethanwoodvine You asked for a C++ solution. If you are looking for a C (with iostream) solution you should mention it in the question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Well, I'm baffled. Even changing from `{}` to `()` doesn't change your example, but that should mean we definitely don't initialise from a list, but definitely call the iterators constructor.

Comment: @underscore_d My mistake. I passed the arguments wrong. You were right.

Comment: I'm guessing WandBox wants one discrete argument per line, so treated the original set of space-delimited arguments as 'one quoted argument'.

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, each line is wrapped in quotation marks

Comment: @ethanwoodvine Assuming that means you _can_ `#include <string>` if not `<vector>`, then simply loop over the C strings and convert them to `std::string` and `count` in that, one at a time. Or find the `\0` terminator yourself and do `std::count(argv[i], argv[i] + len, '.')`. Or there are plenty other ways. From C++17, using an `std::string_view` and then `count()`ing in that would be preferable, as that avoids an unnecessary string copy, but I'm guessing the artificial limitations set by your tutor will exclude that :-(

Comment: these are the only ones we can use
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>  
, i tired making a basic counter but it didnt work,

Comment: @ethanwoodvine: In future, please specify all constraints in the question.

Comment: @ethanwoodvine `time.h` and `math.h` are C headers and shouldn't be used in C++. You should replace them with `ctime` and `cmath`.

Comment: @ethanwoodvine: Please show us your attempt of making a counter, we can then tell you why it is not working.